# what are pros and cons of using HttpContext-based cache vs. System.Runtime.Cache?

Tags: asp.net, .net, caching, .net-4.0

I'm in a webapplication so either `HttpContext` or `HttpContextBase` will be available. I'm wondering what are the differences that would weigh in on choosing one over the other if any?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx

vs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Well, this sentence in the `System.Runtime.Caching` documentation says most of it:

> "The classes in this namespace provide a way to use caching facilities
>   like those in ASP.NET, but without a dependency on the System.Web
>   assembly."

Use the one in the `System.Web` namespace if it's a web application, and the other if it's not.

Comment: no other differences? same system, different assemblies? really?

Comment: @Maslow: Yes, there are other differences, like that there are some web specific methods in the web cache, or that the web cache uses the term "dependency" where the runtime cache uses "monitor", but the biggest difference is that they are targeted for different application types.